# Best fitting rectangular mesh to a smooth 3D surface

Tags: python, visualization, mesh, data-fitting

G'day, I'm struggling to find a way to create a rectangular mesh that best fits a smooth 3D surface. Particularly I have a model of an earthquake fault shown in [this](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/data/slab/images/cas_slab1.jpg) plot.

These are the depth contours to the fault. I want to find a rectangular mesh of defined dimension (say 10x10km) that best fits the surface. It doesn't have to (and it can't) be exactly on the surface, just the closest possible and it HAS to be a rectangle, not just a quadrangle. I have the nodes that define the surface and I can easily interpolate them.

Python solutions are welcome or suggestions on open-source code that my tackle this. I've tried commercial meshers (ABAQUS) but they always return quadrangles. I haven't been able to figure this out so any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the nodes that define the surface, that means you have an irregular grid of coordinates and corresponding values. So you can generate a *triangulation* from this (most likely the tool you're using to show these filled contours uses the same behind the screens).

Matplotlib has two very useful classes that can convert a triangulation to a [rectilinear grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grid) (the more generic form of a rectangular grid): [LinearTriInterpolator](http://matplotlib.org/api/tri_api.html#matplotlib.tri.LinearTriInterpolator) and [CubicTriInterpolator](http://matplotlib.org/api/tri_api.html#matplotlib.tri.CubicTriInterpolator). They are being used in [this matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/triinterp_demo.html).

These are the basic steps from that same example, annotated by me, but credit goes to the matplotlib contributors:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as mtri
import numpy as np

# Create triangulation.
coords, earthquake_fault = get_coordinate_data() # to be filled in by you
x = coords['x']
y = coords['y']
triang = mtri.Triangulation(x, y)

# Interpolate to regularly-spaced quad grid.
z = earthquake_fault # the "height" data
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(x.min(), x.max() 20), np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 20))

interp_lin = mtri.LinearTriInterpolator(triang, z)
zi_lin = interp_lin(xi, yi)

# Plot the triangulation.
plt.subplot(121)
plt.tricontourf(triang, z)
plt.triplot(triang, 'ko-')
plt.title('Triangular grid')

# Plot linear interpolation to quad grid.
plt.subplot(122)
plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi_lin)
plt.title('Rectangular grid')
```